# Django: Store many forms into one table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm using django v1.8.

A have one table split into four forms.

Example from my `views.py`

```
ext_cent = ExternalCentersForm(request.POST, prefix='extcent')
ext_cent_diagnostic = ExternalCentersDiagnosticForm(request.POST,prefix='extcentDiagn')
ext_cent_outcomes = ExternalCentersOutcomesForm(request.POST,prefix='extcentOutcomes')
ext_cent_outcomes2 = ExternalCentersOutcomes2Form(request.POST,prefix='extcentOutcomesTwo')
```

When I'm trying to save them I use

```
ext_cent_object = ext_cent.save(commit=False)
ext_cent_object.author = request.user
ext_cent_object.save()
ext_cent_diagnostic_object = ext_cent_diagnostic.save(commit=False)
ext_cent_diagnostic_object.author = request.user
ext_cent_diagnostic_object.save()
ext_cent_outcomes_object = ext_cent_outcomes.save(commit=False)
ext_cent_outcomes_object.author = request.user
ext_cent_outcomes_object.save()
ext_cent_outcomes2_object = ext_cent_outcomes2.save(commit=False)
ext_cent_outcomes2_object.author = request.user
ext_cent_outcomes2_object.save()
```

My `forms.py`:

```
class ExternalCentersForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExternalCentersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        #self.fields['patient'].queryset = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id=self.instance.patient)
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '<b>Center Information</b>',
                Div(
                        #HTML(u'<br/><div class="col-md-9"><h4><b>Molecular analysis</b></h4></div><br/><br/>'),
                        Div('location_of_center',css_class='col-md-6'),
                        Div('name_of_center',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('type_of_center',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        css_class='row',
                        ),

                ),


            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Ext_centers
        exclude = ['center_id', 'author']
        list_display = ('title', 'pub_date', 'author')


class ExternalCentersDiagnosticForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExternalCentersDiagnosticForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        #self.fields['patient'].queryset = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id=self.instance.patient)
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '<b>Diagnostic categories</b>',
                Div(
                        HTML(u'<div class="col-md-9"><h4><b>Paroxysmal nocturnal haemoglobinuria (PNH)</b></h4></div>'),
                        Div('diagn_categ_pnh_no_patient',css_class='col-md-6'),
                        Div('diagn_categ_pnh_distribution',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        css_class='row',
                        ),


                ),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Ext_centers
        exclude = ['center_id', 'author']
        list_display = ('title', 'pub_date', 'author')

class ExternalCentersOutcomesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExternalCentersOutcomesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        #self.fields['patient'].queryset = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id=self.instance.patient)
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '<b>1. Deaths</b>',
                Div(
                        HTML(u'<div class="col-md-9"><h4><b>2015</b></h4></div>'),
                        Div('outcomes_year2015_thal',css_class='col-md-6'),
                        Div('outcomes_year2015_sickle',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('outcomes_year2015_rare',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        css_class='row',
                        ),
                ),


            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Ext_centers
        exclude = ['center_id', 'author']
        list_display = ('title', 'pub_date', 'author')


class ExternalCentersOutcomes2Form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExternalCentersOutcomes2Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        #self.fields['patient'].queryset = Demographic.objects.filter(patient_id=self.instance.patient)
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '<b>2. More measurements</b>',
                Div(
                        #HTML(u'<br/><div class="col-md-9"><h4><b>Molecular analysis</b></h4></div><br/><br/>'),
                        Div('out_patients_married',css_class='col-md-6'),
                        Div('out_patients_divorced',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('out_patients_single',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('out_patients_cohabiting',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('out_patients_parented_children',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('out_thal_women_preg',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        Div('out_patients_splene',css_class="col-md-6"),
                        css_class='row',
                        ),
                ),


            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Ext_centers
        exclude = ['center_id', 'author']
        list_display = ('title', 'pub_date', 'author')
```

Example from `models.py`

```
class Ext_centers(models.Model):
    center_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    center_city  = models.CharField('City',max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    center_country  = models.CharField('Country',max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    center_name_of_medical_director  = models.CharField('Name of medical director',max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    center_name_of_respondent  = models.CharField('Name of respondent',max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    center_status_of_respondent  = models.CharField('Status of respondent',max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    center_telephone = models.IntegerField('Telephone', null=True,blank=True)
    center_email = models.EmailField('E-mail',null=True,blank=True)
    center_fax = models.IntegerField('Fax',null=True,blank=True)
    center_website = models.CharField('Website',max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    ....

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_of_center
```

As I result for each form I have a new row in my table containing only values from the specific form. I need to store all these form's data into one table.

Comment: Post your form also please.

Comment: @itzmeontv I added my forms right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the place of save You need "update"

Here is an example :

```
    ext_cent_stored = Ext_centers.objects.get(center_id=ext_cent_object.center_id) 

    form = ExternalCentersForm(request.POST, instance=ext_cent_stored)
                if form.is_valid():
                     form.save()

    form = ExternalCentersDiagnosticForm(request.POST, prefix='extcentDiagn',instance=ext_cent_stored)
                if form.is_valid():
                     form.save()

    form = ExternalCentersOutcomesForm(request.POST,prefix='extcentOutcomes', instance=ext_cent_stored)
                if form.is_valid():
                     form.save()

    form = ExternalCentersOutcomes2Form(request.POST,prefix='extcentOutcomesTwo', instance=ext_cent_stored)
                if form.is_valid():
                     form.save()
```

Use this for every save method and you will not lose old data.

Thanks.

Comment: Do I have to include this for the first form or for only the rest 3? Because The first is insertion and then update fields.

Comment: Also I want to insert forms's data to one table and make no update.

Comment: Do You want to save all the object's author into same entry of Ext_centers Table?

Comment: I want to save data I inserted through a form from template. The author I get it from the user in order to add it to the table. So, I have ONE table having author field and I use 4 forms to store data into that ONE table. I will add the model in my question right now.

Comment: Try my new answer. With this,you can save all the authors into one field.

Comment: No, I don' t want to save all the authors into one field. I have a table and for this form I have four separate forms. I need to get all data from these 4 forms and save them to corresponding fields in the table.

Comment: You are saying "save them to corresponding fields in the table." What are those corresponding fields in table ?

Comment: Each form contains some fields from `Ext_centers` table. This means that all fields from that table are separated into four forms.

Comment: Okay,Now I got the whole idea.In that case,you will definetely need update method insted of save for next 3 updations.

Comment: Great! Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Using this code, when I save data to the table using data from the 2nd form, the previously stored data from first form are then empty even though it saved them earlier.

Comment: `center_id` is auto increment so I have to store data from the first form and then extract it.

Comment: I made my code like this: `ext_cent_object = ext_cent.save(commit=False)
        ext_cent_object.author = request.user
        ext_cent_object.save()
        ext_cent_stored = Ext_centers.objects.get(center_id=ext_cent_object.center_id) ext_cent_diagnostic = ExternalCentersDiagnosticForm(request.POST, prefix='extcentDiagn', instance= ext_cent_stored)
       ext_cent_diagnostic.save()`

Comment: And as a result I have the missed values I say to a previous comment.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem remains. When I store data from a form the previously data save from other form are cleared and in the row are stored only the latest.

Comment: Then I am so sorry,I can't seem to find the exact solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Your code is correct. The problem was in my `forms.py` code. In each form I have to exclude the fields that will be input from the other forms, otherwise these fields are updated getting an null value.